# Generic mobile tests with appium

Tags: android, ios, mobile, appium

I'm new to mobile testing , and currently I research for an automation framework for mobile testing.
I've started to look into Appium, and created some tests for the demo app I've made (one for IOS and the other for Android).
I've managed to write a test for each of the platforms , but I was wondering , how difficult it might be to write a one generic test which will be executed on the both platforms with minimum adjustments ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but you have to keep same labels for each component for all platforms, for example to click on a button, instead of locating through Xpath locate by its name.

WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("my button")); button.click();

More info finding elements in Appium docs:
http://appium.wikia.com/wiki/Finding_Elements

Answer (score 1):

I built an automation framework from scratch which does exactly the same thing, i.e. have one code base and the tests run both on Android and iOS based on what device and app you give the test. This is how I went about doing it. (*I used Java+Appium+Cucumber framework*).

- Following the Page Object pattern is a good practice for writing automation code.

That being said, you will have all the resource ids of Android and Accessibility ids of iOS in 2 separate files under a folder named say **"ObjectRepository"**. These files usually have the extension of `*.properties` (*It is called the properties file*).

Say you have a Login button that you want to interact with on Android and iOS, you have will 2 files:

File 1) **"androidObject.properties"** which has:

`Login.LoginButton=loginAndroidBtn`

File 2) **"iOSObject.properties"** which has:

`Login.LoginButton=loginiOSBtn`

> **NOTE:** In the key/value pair above, the key is the same "Login.LoginButton", the value is the resource id and the accessibility id of the Login Button in your Android and iOS application

In your code you would do the following:

```
if(IS_ANDROID) {

DRIVER.findElementById("Login.LoginButton").click();

 } else {

  DRIVER.findElementByAccessibilityId("Login.LoginButton").click();
 }
```

In another file you would set what `IS_ANDROID` and `IS_IOS` means. You may do something like this:

```
 public static DeviceConfig DEVICE_CONFIG;

  private void setPlatform() {

     if (DEVICE_CONFIG.platformName.equals("Android")) {

         IS_ANDROID = true;

     } else if (DEVICE_CONFIG.platformName.equals("iOS")) {

          IS_IOS = true;
   }
```

This way you can have one code base and run Android and iOS seamlessly.